# How realistic is it for Gus Fring to dig a tunnel between two houses across the road?

Tags: realism, better-call-saul

In Batter Call Saul, season 6, we have seen multiple times that there is an underground tunnel between Gus Fring's personal residence and the house opposite to his house across the road.

The two houses are in a really good and quiet neighbourhood.

I can only assume digging a tunnel is not legal, letting alone the tunnel is very well constructed with concrete reinforcement and etc. How realistic is it for Gus to pull it off in a quiet neighbourhood like his?

Comment: Somehow, I don't think Gus Fring is the kind of person who lets trivial things like the law get in his way.

Comment: Wellll, after the making of a cavernous supelab site, I don't see how a tiny tunnel between basements could matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many tunnels that are much longer and even “more illegal” have been discovered in the real world.

Earlier in 2022, a tunnel was found that crosses underneath the U.S.-Mexico border that was over 500m long, had steel reinforcing beams, lighting, ventilation, and a rail system.

In 2020, a cross-border tunnel was found that was over 1300m long. Other tunnels for smuggling of various kinds have been found at the U.S.-Mexico border and at other controlled borders around the world.

See: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-61477775.amp

Comment: People [at least in movies] dug a constant stream of tunnels out of PoW camps in the war… even with guards actively looking out for evidence of such activity ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin The world has moved on from the time when it was clear which war “the war” refers to. ;-)

Comment: I was intentionally vague, leaving it as a movie trope ;)

Comment: Also, Basil Fawlty - "Don't mention the war".

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it is absolutely clear to me what "the war" refers to. I just asked my grandson aged 16, and he said 'thirty nine forty-five', and added 'the Great War was fourteen eighteen'.